# Between date in long SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I get the USER ID and the count of rows from the most common user id in the table 'tickets'. But now, I want to do the same query but it needs to search between 2 datetimes I insert. ( there is an column with a datetime value ('created_at'))

This is the code I have:

```
SELECT created_by,COUNT(*) as tickets_count
FROM tickets
WHERE created_at
group by created_by having count(*) =(select max(tickets_count) from (select created_by,count(*) as tickets_count from tickets group by created_by) tickets)
```

This is the table:

[image: Click on image]

I already tried:

```
SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) as tickets_count
FROM tickets
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2021-07-25 10:00:00' AND ' 2021-07-30 12:00:00'
group by created_by
having count(*) =(select max(tickets_count) from (select created_by,count(*) as tickets_count from tickets group by created_by) tickets)
```

But it gave me 0 rows, which isn't true because ID 6 is between those 2 days.

Comment: There's a leading space on one of your date constants. That may break your WHERE filter.

Comment: @O.Jones removed it, still it don't work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for one user, you can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) as tickets_count
FROM tickets
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2021-07-25 10:00:00' AND ' 2021-07-30 12:00:00'
GROUP BY created_by
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want all users when there are duplicates, use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) as tickets_count,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tickets
      WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2021-07-25 10:00:00' AND ' 2021-07-30 12:00:00'
      GROUP BY created_by
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

````sql
SELECT created_by,COUNT(*) as tickets_count FROM tickets WHERE date(created_at) BETWEEN date('2021-07-25 10:00:00') AND date(' 2021-07-30 12:00:00') group by created_by having count(*) =(select max(tickets_count) from (select created_by,count(*) as tickets_count from tickets group by created_by) tickets) ```
````

Comment: Hi, thanks for your idea. SQL code works but still 0 rows.

Comment: can you create `sqlfiddle` link for testing?